# LINQ query Concat values to list of type string

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

```
List<String> lstReferences = (from f in 
                            (from section in courseSectionToCreate.SectionsToAdd
                                select new {
                                            ReferenceNumber = section.Course.CourseNumber.Substring(0, 5) + "." +
                                                section.Course.CourseNumber.Substring(5) + "." +
                                                section.Session + "." +
                                                section.Year + "." +
                                                section.SectionNumber + ";"
                                            })
                            select f.ReferenceNumber).ToList();

strReferenceNumber = lstReferences.Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all that with this:

```
var strReferenceNumber =
    String.Join(", ",
        courseSectionToCreate.SectionsToAdd.Select(s =>
            String.Join(".", 
                s.Course.CourseNumber.Substring(0, 5),
                s.Course.CourseNumber.Substring(5),
                s.Session,
                s.Year,
                s.SectionNumber) + ";"
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it appears to be processing the fastest on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you definitely don't want to be using `Aggregate` here. That is `O(n^2)` (it's [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_Painter%27s_algorithm)). Instead:

```
string referenceNumber = String.Join(", ", lstReferences);
```

This is better because `String.Join` will use a `StringBuilder` internally.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var lstReferences = from section in courseSectionToCreate.SectionsToAdd     
                    let courseNumber = section.Course.CourseNumber                           
                    let toJoin = new object[] 
                    { 
                       courseNumber.Substring(0, 5),
                       courseNumber.Substring(5),
                       section.Session,
                       section.Year,
                       section.SectionNumber
                    }
                    select string.Join(".", toJoin) + ";" 

var strReferenceNumber = string.Join(", ", lstReferences);
```

Comment: I doubt (but don't know) that that will cooperate with LINQ to SQL (or other queryable providers like that). That is an important consideration.

Comment: @Jason: Is this LINQ to SQL? Doesn't look like it, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @Jason: It could be. Was an impression; there doesn't appear to be a data-context.

Comment: @Jason: LINQ to SQL can definitely handle the string methods used here (`String.Join()`, `String.Concat()` and `String.Substring()`) so it's not a problem.

Comment: @Jeff M: Are you sure about `String.Join`, especially the way that it is being invoked?

Comment: I have my doubts this would work if this were not LINQ to Objects. I'm hoping the OP can clarify..

Comment: @Jason: Now that you mention it, I don't know if it works when called that way.  I'll double check.

Comment: @Jason: Yes, that way does work.  Just note that LINQ to SQL will generate the query to get the individual columns needed to build the string.  But not to create the string itself.

Comment: Either way, the big issue here is the use of `Aggregate`, not the concatenation internal to the query. It's small enough that it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: This was not LINQ to SQL, but it worked perfectly (as soon as I added a closing semi-colon) and answered another question I had, thanks!